# androidで動画撮影中に撮影時間を取得するには

Tags: android

androidでMediaRecorderで動画撮影中に撮影時間を画面に表示しています。
撮影開始と同時にタイマーをスタートして撮影時間を求めて画面に表示しています。
撮影停止したときに、画面上は3秒となっていますが、撮影した動画ファイルが2秒の場合がありました。
端末によっては3秒もあり、端末で結果が異なっていました。

動画撮影中に正確な撮影時間を求める方法はあるのでしょうか？
アドバイスをよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: MediaRecorderには遅延があるので、リアルタイムで正確な時間を取得することは困難な可能性が高いです。
録画後であれば、近しい値を取れるとの情報がありましたので、こちらを参考にしてみてはいかがでしょうか。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35386663/android-detecting-real-recording-mediarecorder-has-delay
もしくは https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217536/is-there-any-way-to-get-duration-of-ongoing-recording